# removing lambdas from the below class in java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the below java class which is using `Stream`s as shown below. I have one basic class named person and then there is other class in which I am using `Stream`s.

Is there any way through which I can avoid the lambdas and remove them?

```
public class StreamMapDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

        personList.add(new Person("Alice", "alice@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 16));
        personList.add(new Person("Bob", "bob@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 15));
        personList.add(new Person("Carol", "carol@gmail.com", Gender.FEMALE, 23));
        personList.add(new Person("David", "david@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 19));
        personList.add(new Person("Eric", "eric@gmail.com", Gender.MALE, 26));

        personList.stream()                     // Stream<Person>
                  .map(p -> p.getEmail())      //  Stream<String>
                  .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\n----------------------\n");

        personList.stream()  // Stream<Person>
                  .map(p -> p.getName().toUpperCase()) //  Stream<String>
                  .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\n----------------------\n");

        personList.stream()  // Stream<Person>
                  .mapToInt(p -> p.getAge()) //IntStream
                  .forEach(age -> System.out.println(age));

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
alice@gmail.com
bob@gmail.com
carol@gmail.com
david@gmail.com
eric@gmail.com

----------------------

ALICE
BOB
CAROL
DAVID
ERIC

----------------------

16
15
23
19
26
```

Comment: Convert the code using regular loops.

Comment: remove lamda or streams ?

Comment: It may help if you said *why* you want to remove the lambda expressions. Some people here are unclear if you want to remove just the lambdas or also the streams. And one has to wonder what's wrong with lambda expressions.

Comment: You could have used the for loops or foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method references instead of lambda expressions:

```
personList.stream()                     
    .map(Person::getEmail)        
    .forEach(System.out::println);

personList.stream()
    .map(Person::getName)
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .forEach(System.out::println);

personList.stream()  
    .mapToInt(Person::getAge) 
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I'm unsure if OP also wants to avoid **streams**. But if not, then this might indeed be the alternative he is searching for. Definitely looks more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you also don't want to use **streams**, here is a version using **regular loops** like in *the old days*:

```
for (final Person person : personList) {
    System.out.println(person.getEmail());
}

System.out.println("\n----------------------\n");

for (final Person person : personList) {
    System.out.println(person.getName().toUpperCase());
}

System.out.println("\n----------------------\n");

for (final Person person : personList) {
    System.out.println(person.getAge());
}
```

---

Or all together, if you want to **group by person**:

```
for (final Person person : personList) {
    System.out.println(person.getEmail());
    System.out.println(person.getName().toUpperCase());
    System.out.println(person.getAge());
    System.out.println("----------------------");
}
```

Note that this version slightly changes the output. However it is faster, you only need one iteration and not three.

The output then is like:

```
alice@gmail.com
ALICE
16
----------------------
bob@gmail.com
BOB
15
```